# Excel: Replace text in next row on base of selection criteria on previous

Tags: excel, vba

I have big excel sheet data like below

```
10.11.0.5,PCS
10.11.0.6,Reserve
10.11.0.7,Reserve
10.11.0.8,Reserve
10.11.0.9,PCS
10.11.0.10,Reserve
10.11.0.11,Reserve
10.11.0.12,Reserve
```

Now i want to replace **Reserve** to **PLC** which is next to **PCS**

Expected output should be like

```
10.11.0.5,PCS
10.11.0.6,PLC
10.11.0.7,Reserve
10.11.0.8,Reserve
10.11.0.9,PCS
10.11.0.10,PLC
10.11.0.11,Reserve
10.11.0.12,Reserve
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, Add formula to next cell

[image]